# How to return the hierarchy from a table using sql server query or code?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, hierarchical-data

I have been asked these two questions and were not able to answer, I figured it involves a simple `SELECT` query that is being used with recursion.

1. Represent a windows directory hierarchy in a database where there is one parent directory (Drive C:) and the rest are children directories and children of children directories.

   (My answer: a table with 2 columns `id INT, parentId INT`)
2. Now write SQL code that will take a directory id and will return all its children folders and children of children folders and so on.

Comment: this on is very related ... http://stackoverflow.com/q/16759496/1699210

Comment: If you can, use the hierarchyid field type.

Answer (score 0):

The "with" solution in the comment is probably the expected answer if this is an SqlServer specific test. It might even be suitable in some real life situations.

In other situations you may want a stored procedure, or model the tree as "nested sets", or not use a relational database at all. (neo4j is a likely candidate)